# How to change a primary key in SQL to auto_increment?

Tags: sql, mysql, primary-key, auto-increment, alter-table

I have a table in MySQL that has a primary key:

```
mysql> desc gifts;
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| giftID        | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| name          | varchar(80) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| filename      | varchar(80) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| effectiveTime | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

but I wanted to make it auto_increment.

The following statement failed.  How can it be modified so that it can work?  thanks

```
mysql> alter table gifts modify giftID int primary key auto_increment;
ERROR 1068 (42000): Multiple primary key defined
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Leave off the `primary key` attribute:

```
ALTER TABLE gifts MODIFY giftID INT AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Certain column attributes, such as `PRIMARY KEY`, aren't exactly properties of the column so much as shortcuts for other things.  A column marked `PRIMARY KEY`, for example, is placed in the `PRIMARY` index. Futhermore, all columns in the `PRIMARY` index are given the `NOT NULL` attribute. (Aside: to have a multi-column primary key, you must use a separate constraint clause rather than multiple `PRIMARY KEY` column attributes.) Since the column is already in the `PRIMARY` index, you don't need to specify it again when you modify the column. Try `SHOW CREATE TABLE gifts;` to see the affects of using the `PRIMARY KEY` attribute.

Comment: great thanks!  "ALTER TABLE gifts MODIFY giftID AUTO_INCREMENT" seems like needing "INT" -- "alter table gifts modify giftID int auto_increment;"

Comment: Does not work when there is a foreign key constraint that uses the primary key on MySQL server 5.7.  I get 
"Cannot change column 'id': used in a foreign key constraint 'jobs_ibfk_1' of table 'customers.jobs' "